# mysql SUM Group after max of Date

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, sum, max

I have 2 tables,

Servis table with 
Client_ID
date and 
type (0 or 1)

Sales tables with
Client_ID
date and
product

I need to crate I table that groups Client ID,  calculates sum of product, but only data after last date on Servis table, with type 1

Client | Sum
-------+------
1      | 32
4      | 2

Comment: To get the best out of StackOverflow, have a go yourself and when you're stuck, post your code for help ...

Comment: I searched, but my problem is that I have more than one date of max, and I need to calsulate only with the last one
this is what i treid but I get this error:Operand should contain 1 column(s)

SELECT MAX(dataservis) AS tt, klientiID, MASGJ
FROM servis
WHERE MASGJ = 1 AND 
(
SELECT emrishitja, datashitja, grand
FROM  shitja
WHERE  dataservis < datashitja  AND emrishitja =  klientiID
)
GROUP BY klientiID